# DBPedia Spotlight Docker Image unable to start

Tags: dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I am trying to run DBPedia Spotlight locally with Docker-compose (also tried Docker run) with the following configuraiton:

```
services:
  spotlight.en:
    image: dbpedia/dbpedia-spotlight
    container_name: dbpedia-spotlight.en
    volumes:
      - spotlight-model:/opt/spotlight/models
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:2222:80"
    command: /bin/spotlight.sh en


volumes:
  spotlight-model:
    external: true
```

The container starts and shows as runing, but all request like the example:

```
curl http://localhost:2222/rest/annotate \
    --data-urlencode "text=President Obama called Wednesday on Congress to extend a tax break for students included in last year's economic stimulus package, arguing that the policy provides more generous assistance." \
    --data "confidence=0.35" \
    -H "Accept: text/turtle"
```

fails with "**curl: (52) Empty reply from server**" error. Examining the container logs on docker, I found the following errors:

[image]

There is no mention of the URL that curl is trying to retrieve the file from, so I have no idea where to find it. I am also running docker on Mac with M2 chips, am not sure this is relevant (there is a warning on Docker)!